# Ubuntu 23.04 won't fully boot from .iso

Tags: iso, 23.04

Currently running Ubuntu 22.10, no problems.

**Config**: Dell Inspiron 7700 AIO. 11th gen I7. 32G RAM, latest BIOS.

I try to "test drive" Ubuntu 23.04 and get mixed results...

I made the appropriate mods to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` like seen in the following code fragment...

```
menuentry "Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop ISO (external disk)" {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        rmmod tpm
        set root=(hd0,gpt1)
        set isofile="/ubuntu-23.04-desktop-amd64.iso"
        loopback loop $isofile
        linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile quiet splash
        initrd (loop)/casper/initrd
}
```

This boots the 23.04 .iso file (with verbose logging I do see DEPENDS error messages for SSSD) to a desktop pattern with a solid blue color (not the 23.04 default desktop pattern), and a top menu bar that only contains the sound icon and the battery icon. I can use the quick menu to connect to my wireless network. That's about it. No Activities menu, no dash, can't open the Terminal app, and can't get to the Applications page.

**Note**: I use the exact same code fragment to boot a 22.10 .iso and it works fine.

Now, the interesting part is that I can boot to a 23.04 USB flash drive (that I used the exact same .iso file to build), and it all works fine!

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using the standard Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop iso file, and it has a new installer *and* a new linux line in `grub.cfg`. The legacy Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop iso file works with the old version of menuentry and the 23.04 community flavours too.

See [this link to an Ubuntu help wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot#Menuentry_Example), where I put a modified menuentry that works (I tested it).

```
linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper layerfs-path=minimal.standard.live.squashfs iso-scan/filename=$isofile
```

Comment: Fantastic! It works just fine now. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome @heynnema, I'm glad that I could help such a guru  :-)

Comment: We all stick together... and it works :-)

Comment: I don't like that 23.04 .iso boots straight into the Installer :-(

Comment: I agree. There was a boot option to control that with Ubiquity, and Lubuntu manages Calamares without booting straight into it. Maybe there is a boot option also in this case, but we don't know about it.